# Image size in RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

We are displaying image in RDLC report. Currently we are setting image size to autosize however it causes a page-break. Kindly let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to define a preferred size and set the image sizing property to `FitProportional` or `Clip`.

Another solution is to add a second image object with the above suggested settings below your original image. Then define an expression for both images that checks the size of the image. If the image size exceeds the size of the page, display the second image and hide the first. Else, show the first and hide the second.
The actual maximum size that causes the page break, is something you'll have to figure out yourself.